# Possível erro na logíca de uma função que retorna se um inteiro é um numero de Armstrong

Tags: c

Números de Armstrong são números que são a soma dos seus próprios dígitos, cada um elevado ao número de dígitos.
Ex: 371 (3 dígitos) = 3³ + 7³ + 1³.
Sabendo disso, meu algoritmo dá erro com o número 153 e somente com ele (o programa me dá o resultado errado, ou seja, a função retorna 0), não consegui descobrir o porquê. Eu compilo pelo gcc através do vscode.

Alguns números de Armstrong para teste: do 1 ao 9, 153, 370, 371, 407, 1654.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int eh_numero_de_armstrong(int n);

int main()
{
  int x;

  printf("Digite um numero qualquer: ");
  scanf("%d", &x);

  if (eh_numero_de_armstrong(x))
    printf("%d eh um numero de Armstrong.\n", x);
  else
    printf("%d nao eh um numero de Armstrong.\n", x);

  return 0;
}

int eh_numero_de_armstrong(int n)
{
  char str[100];
  int soma_alg = 0;

  sprintf(str, "%d", n);
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    soma_alg += pow(str[i] - '0', strlen(str));

  if (n == soma_alg)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Qual seria esse erro? O programa te dá o resultado errado, ou ele crasha? [Aqui](https://onlinegdb.com/SJcv9ngZL) está funcionando normalmente.

Comment: @user140828 me dá o resultado errado, a função retorna 0. (Vou editar a pergunta)

Comment: Aqui funcionou para: 93084, 8208, 1634, 407, 371, 370 e 153.

Comment: Parece que é meu compilador então, vou tentar reinstalá-lo. Testou com o gcc? @anonimo

Comment: Você também pode utilizar algum compilador online como o ideone: https://ideone.com/

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente no gcc. gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O programa estava funcionando para alguns, também funcionou em um compilador online para mim, mas, no fim, fiz uma função para calcular a potência. Só adicionei essa função e troquei o pow por calc_pow no código da pergunta.

Agradeço por tentarem ajudar, @anonimo @user140828

```c
int calc_pow(int base, int exp)
{
  int pow_result = 1;

  for (int i = 1; i <= exp; i++)
    pow_result *= base;

  return pow_result;
}
```